# How to get PRIMARY KEY column name of a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, primary-key

I need to get the PRIMARY KEY COLUMN NAME.
I have the name of my table in a variable called `_lstview_item`

Till now i tried getting the column name like this

```
 string sql = "SELECT ColumnName = col.column_name" +
              "FROM information_schema.table_constraints tc" +
              "INNER JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage col" +
              "ON col.Constraint_Name = tc.Constraint_Name" +
                      "AND col.Constraint_schema = tc.Constraint_schema" +
              "WHERE tc.Constraint_Type = 'Primary Key'" +
                      "AND col.Table_name = " +_lstview_item+ "";

 SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(cc.connectionString(cmb_dblist.Text));
 SqlCommand cmd_server2 = new SqlCommand(sql);
 cmd_server2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 cmd_server2.Connection = conn2;
 conn2.Open();
 string ColumnName = (string)cmd_server2.ExecuteScalar();                 
 conn2.Close();
```

Without any success.
Help ?

Comment: Without any success? Any exception or error message?

Comment: Is it me or there is a problem with quotes in your SQL statement?

Comment: the select statement you specified is returning PK column name correctly. What specific issue you are facing then?

Comment: error message saying invalid column name CurrencyType(my table name :\) .... i think its got to to wth the data already in my dataset.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

this should be your query. You are missing single quotes on your table name. Tested and works fine.

```
string sql = "SELECT ColumnName = col.column_name 
    FROM information_schema.table_constraints tc 
    INNER JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage col 
        ON col.Constraint_Name = tc.Constraint_Name 
    AND col.Constraint_schema = tc.Constraint_schema 
    WHERE tc.Constraint_Type = 'Primary Key' AND col.Table_name = '" + _lstview_item + "'";
```

Comment: The PostgreSql version: SELECT col.column_name
    FROM information_schema.table_constraints tc 
    INNER JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage col 
        ON col.Constraint_Name = tc.Constraint_Name 
    AND col.Constraint_schema = tc.Constraint_schema 
    WHERE 
     lower(tc.Constraint_Type) = lower('Primary Key') 
     AND 
     col.Table_name = 'mytable'

Answer (score 8):

try this:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(constraint_name), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1
AND table_name = 'TableName'
```

Comment: This is true for SqlServer, where answer for Ehsan can be adjusted for PostgeSql too.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's already solved but I did it this way. 
Tested with MSSQL and MYSQL and it works perfectly.

```
public static List<string> GetPrimaryKeyColumns(DbConnection connection, string tableName)
{
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        string[] restrictions = new string[] { null, null, tableName };
        DataTable table = connection.GetSchema("IndexColumns", restrictions);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tableName))
            throw new Exception("Table name must be set.");

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            result.Add(row["column_name"].ToString());
        }

        return result;
}
```